# Error: unexpected end of stream when upload file to server (react native fs)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, file-upload, upload

I am using [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to upload file(images) to server

on backend I am using laravel 5

This is the code to upload the file (should be about same as on their doc)

```
async uploadImageReq(){
    var url = this.API_BASE_URL + '/api/addimages/'
    var uploadBegin = (response) => {
      var jobId = response.jobId;
      console.log('UPLOAD HAS BEGUN! JobId: ' + jobId);
    };

    var uploadProgress = (response) => {
      var percentage = Math.floor((response.totalBytesSent/response.totalBytesExpectedToSend) * 100);
      console.log('UPLOAD IS ' + percentage + '% DONE!');
    };
    console.log('check url', url, files) 
    return await RNFS.uploadFiles({
      toUrl: url,
      files: files,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this._sessionToken,
        'Connection': 'close'
      },
      fields: {
        'hello': 'world',
      },
      begin: uploadBegin,
      progress: uploadProgress
    }).promise.then((response) => {
        console.log('result', response)
        return response
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          console.log('FILES UPLOADED!'); // response.statusCode, response.headers, response.body
        } else {
          console.log('SERVER ERROR');
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if(err.description === "cancelled") {
          // cancelled by user
        }
        console.log('ERROR',err);
      })
  }
```

This throw error

> [Error: unexpected end of stream] framesToPop: 1, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED'

Any idea what cause this error?

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

In my case `Error: Socket is closed, code: 'EUNSPECIFIED'` meant that there was a mistake in the filename.